# Como resto los valores que posee un arreglo (array)

Tags: java, array, bucles, while

esta vez tengo un problema, digamos un tanto "complejo"... Veran estoy haciendo una calculadora en la cual tu introduzcas cuantas variables vas a operar (por ejemplo 5 variables), y despues introduzcas cada una (por ejemplo 2;5;7;1;6) y despues te pregunta que quieres hacer con esos numeros? sumarlos?,restarlos?,multiplicarlos?, dividirlos?... y aqui es donde viene el problema, cuando los sumo todo va bien pero cuando los divido, multiplico  el programa arroja un 0 (osea como que 2*2 es 0?) en caso de la resta el programa me arroja una sumatoria de la resta(osea si yo coloco que reste un 4 y un 5, lo que yo veo 4-5 que deberia dar -1, la maquina lo lee como -4-5 y me arroja un -9)
este es mi codigo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Cuantos numeros quieres Operar?");
    int cantidav;
    int operador;
    int contador = 0;
    
    while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Error, Introduce la cantidad otra vez");
        sc.next();
    }
    cantidav = sc.nextInt();
    
    int [] variables = new int [cantidav];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i<variables.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Introduce las variables");
        while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Solo se aceptan numeros enteros");
            sc.next();
        }
        variables[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }
    
    System.out.println("Perfecto, Ahora que quieres hacer con ellas?");
    
    
    System.out.println("coloca 1 para sumar");
    System.out.println("coloca 2 para restar");
    System.out.println("coloca 3 para multiplicar");
    System.out.println("coloca 4 para division");

    
  
    while(!sc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("lo que introdujistes no coincide con ninguna opcion");
        sc.next();
    }
    do{
        while(sc.hasNextInt() == false){
         System.out.println("lo que introdujistes no coincide con ninguna opcion");
         sc.next();
        }
       operador = sc.nextInt();
         if(operador == 1 || operador == 2 || operador == 3 || operador == 4){
        contador++;
    }else{
         System.out.println("lo que introdujistes no coincide con ninguna opcion"); 
        contador = 0;
    }
    }while(contador<1);
    
    switch(operador){
        case 1:
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        suma+=variables[i];
    }
    System.out.println("La suma de los valores son = "+suma);
    break;
    
        case 2:
        int resultadoresta = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        resultadoresta= resultadoresta - variables[i];
    }
    System.out.println("La resta de los valores son = "+resultadoresta);
    break;
    
        case 3:
        int multi = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        multi*=variables[i];
    }
    System.out.println("La multiplicacion de los valores son = "+multi);
    break;
    
        case 4:
        int divi = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        divi/=variables[i];
    }
    System.out.println("La division de los valores son = "+divi);
    break;

    }
    }
```

Y este es el problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu mismo estas declarando la variable multi como 0 osea todo estas multiplicando por 0 ; inicializalo como 1 y listo ;)

Comment: para la resta o la division podes iniciar las respectivas variables con el primer elemento del array ejemplo `int resta=variables[0];` e iniciar el ciclo for en int i=1 para que no tome el primer valor

Comment: gracias, me sirvio de mucho, entiendo mas o menos la logica, pero lo que sigue sin cuadrarme es en la resta, por ejemplo, si yo pusiera 20,5,6,10 me aparece -1 y con otras combinaciones intente y parece ser que el unico valor al que le puedes dar valor tanto positivo como negativo es al primero (es decir el 20), los demas se tomaran como negativos sin importar que les hayas escrito un sigono de + (por ejemplo poner un +5), la multiplicacion y division andan bien, muchas gracias

Comment: ten en cuenta que aunque pongas + o - delante de un numero ingresado, siempre estará el signo - debido al bucle,por ejemplo si ingresas 20 -3 4 la operación sera 20 -(-3) -4 lo que se convertirá en 20 +3 -4 =19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso te esta pasando porque debes validar cuando tu valor se multiplica, divide o resta con 0, te faltaría colocar una condicional en tu bucle for donde realizas la resta por ejemplo, hice una prueba para las restas y funciona con este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] variables = new int[4];
    variables[0] = 4;
    variables[1] = 5;
    variables[2] = 2;
    variables[3] = 2;
    int resultadoresta = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        if (i>0){
            resultadoresta = resultadoresta - variables[i];
        }else{
            resultadoresta = variables[i] - resultadoresta;
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado de la resta es: " + resultadoresta);
    }
    System.out.println("resultadoresta = " + resultadoresta);//-5
}
```